# Function returns CSV File: How to go about checking it?

Tags: php, csv

I am doing something like:

```
$outputFile = getCurrentDBSnapshot($data);
```

where $data is the resource stream that am passing in, basically from command prompt am passing an file and am opening it using fopen for writing with 'w+' permissions, now getCurrentDBSnapshot would get the current state of a table and would update the $data csv file, so basically $outputFile would be updated with the current state of database table, now I want to var_dump or print the value of $outputFile to see the data present into it.

But when I do

```
$this->fout = fopen($outputFile,'r') or die('Cannot open file');
$test = fgetcsv($outputFile,5000,";");
var_dump($test);
```

It gives me an error saying that it expects parameter 1 to be a string type and am passing resource.

*My goal to see the contains of $outputFile*

and so my question is that

*How can I see the contains present in $outputFile or how can I see what getcurrentDBSnapshot function is returning me ?*

Comment: Is this question not clear ? Is something that is missing out that would be make this more useful question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fegtcsv` takes as first parameter a file handle, not a filename. You'll need to do something like:

```
$this->fout = fopen($outputFile,'r') or die('Cannot open file');
while ($test = fgetcsv($this->fout,5000,";"))
{
    var_dump($test);
}
```

Note that `fgetcsv` merely gets a single line of the file, analogously to fgets.

Also I'm not sure why you're passing a semicolon as the third argument to `fgetcsv`. CSV stands for comma-separated-value; are you sure your file is semicolon-delimited?

Comment: Yes, my file is semicolon delimited, also `fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given` and value for `var_dump($test)` is `NULL`

Comment: CSV files are semi-colon delimited in some countries (e.g. France)

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [`fgetcsv`](http://fr.php.net/fgetcsv) page of the manual, the first parameter passed to `fgetcsv` should be :

> A valid file pointer to a file
>   successfully opened by `fopen()`,
>   `popen()`, or `fsockopen()`.

Here, you are passing as first parameter `$outputFile`, which contains the name of the file you are trying to read from -- i.e. a string, and not a handle to an opened file.

Considering you are calling `fopen` and storing its return-value in `$this->fout`, this is probably the variable you should be passing to `fgetcsv`, like this :

```
$this->fout = fopen($outputFile,'r') or die('Cannot open file');
$test = fgetcsv($this->fout,5000,";");
var_dump($test);
```

As a sidenote : `fgetcsv` will only return the data of one line each time you call it -- which means you might have to use a loop, if you want to see the content of the whole file.

If needed, take a look at **Example #1**, on [the manual page of `fgetcsv`](http://fr.php.net/fgetcsv).

Comment: `fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given` and `var_dump($test)` gives `NULL`